# Error checking a byte array

Tags: serial-port, arduino, error-checking

What is the best way to check if the data in a byte array is correct?

I am sending a byte array across a serial connection, for example, byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, and errorCheckByte, and I want to check the data is correct when I receive it.

What is the best mathematical operation to perform on the first four bytes to determine they are the same on both ends of the connection? Should I just add them all together?

For example, but not actually looking for a language specific example, but this relates to Java and Arduino:

```
byte byte1 = 5;
byte byte2 = 10;
byte byte3 = 34;
byte byte4 = 122;

byte errorCheckByte = createErrorByte(byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4);

byte myArray[] = {byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, errorCheckByte}

byte createErrorByte(byte byte1,byte byte2, byte byte3, byte byte4)
{return (byte1 + byte2 + byte3 + byte4);}
```

After sending I could perhaps check using the following?

```
// Sum bytes received
byte sumBytes = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 3 ; x++) {sumBytes += myArray[x]}

if (myArray[4] == sumBytes) { // Print message received}
else {
    // Discard data
}
```

Is there a better, but simple, error-check algorithm?

Comment: A checksum may be better than no test at all, but a CRC is much, much better.  A simple sum will not detect swapped bytes, but CRC will.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the concept of [hashing/checksumming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum). For small amounts of data, the [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) method is a common choice, for example, CRC32.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example function to compute a CRC of 8 bits from 4 bytes worth of data, I've read those articles and although useful I am not sufficiently good at maths to work it out myself.

Comment: @Zac Yes, it's definitely possible. Why not google "CRC implementation C"?